# select query to filter gridview according to options asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

net web application and i need to filter gridview according to some option>

the data base contain these tables :

```
***********************************
user           *  warning
***********************************
id             *   id
firstname      *   user_id
lastname       *   type
fathername     *   content
               *   title
               *   date
               *   writer1
               *   writer2
               *   committeecoordinator
               *   youthcoordinator
```

the user.id = warning.user_id
and i need to filter according to 4 options :

dropdownlist for type
dropdownlist for firstname+fathername+lastname from user
textbox for date
textbox for title

I need the grid view to bring all the information and after changing the option it's rebind with the new record that verified the options

I write these query :

```
        SELECT 
    warning.id, warning.user_id, warning.type, warning.title, warning.xcontent, 
warning.xdate, warning.writer1, warning.writer2, warning.committeecoordinator, 
warning.youthcoordinator, 
user.firstname + ' ' + user.fathername + ' ' + user.lastname AS name 
FROM warning INNER JOIN user ON warning.user_id = user.id
```

but don't know how to add the filter to this query

i tried to add where warning.type=@warning but didn't work

option code :

```
<table align="right" cellpadding="7px">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <span class="brownfont">name</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="userlist" CssClass="select" runat="server" DataSourceID="userdatasource" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userdatasource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc %>" SelectCommand="SELECT id, (firstname +' '+fathername+' ' +lastname) AS name FROM sarcuser"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                    <td width="70px">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <span class="brownfont">type<span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="type" CssClass="select" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <span class="brownfont">title</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="title" CssClass="textfield" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td width="70px">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <span class="brownfont">date</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="xdate" CssClass="NjmeDine_Date textfield" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" align="left">
                        <asp:Button class="button" ID="filter" runat="server" Text="seach" OnClick="filter_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="warningdatasource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM sarcwarning WHERE (id = @id)" SelectCommand="SELECT sarcwarning.id, sarcwarning.user_id, sarcwarning.type, sarcwarning.title, sarcwarning.xcontent, sarcwarning.xdate, sarcwarning.writer1, sarcwarning.writer2, sarcwarning.committeecoordinator, sarcwarning.youthcoordinator, sarcuser.firstname + ' ' + sarcuser.fathername + ' ' + sarcuser.lastname AS name FROM sarcwarning INNER JOIN sarcuser ON sarcwarning.user_id = sarcuser.id ">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="userlist" DefaultValue="%" Name="user_id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="title" DefaultValue="%" Name="title" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="type" DefaultValue="%" Name="type" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="xdate" DefaultValue="%" Name="xdate" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

please could you help me

Comment: Show the code where you add the parameter to the query

Comment: I edit my code up there

Comment: Your query uses an @warning parameter but I can't see that parameter anywhere in your code. Try setting that parameter in your select parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in the code : 
the problem is when I compare user_id from database(int) and from control selected value(string)

so the right solution is :

where (user_id +'' like @id)

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="warningdatasource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc.ProviderName %>"  
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM sarcwarning WHERE (id = @id)" 
    SelectCommand= "SELECT w.id, w.user_id, w.type, w.title, w.xcontent, w.xdate, w.writer1, w.writer2, w.committeecoordinator, w.youthcoordinator, u.firstname + ' ' + u.fathername + ' ' + u.lastname AS name FROM sarcwarning AS w INNER JOIN sarcuser AS u ON w.user_id = u.id WHERE (w.user_id +'' like @user_id) AND (w.type like @type) AND (w.title like @title) AND (w.xdate like @xdate)"
    >
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </DeleteParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="userlist" DefaultValue="%" Name="user_id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="type" DefaultValue="%" Name="type" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="title" DefaultValue="%" Name="title" PropertyName="Text" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="xdate" DefaultValue="%" Name="xdate" PropertyName="Text" />
            </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

amazing ASP

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :** You want to display all data in the GridView in page load. So you should remove all 
`SelectParameters` from the SqlDataSource and change the `SelectCommand`. Your `SqlDataSource` should look like this :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="warningdatasource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc.ProviderName %>"  
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM warning WHERE (id = @id)" 
    SelectCommand= "SELECT w.id, w.user_id, w.type, w.title, w.content, w.date, w.writer1, 
                         w.writer2, w.committeecoordinator, w.youthcoordinator, 
                         u.firstname + ' ' + u.fathername + ' ' + u.lastname AS name 
                        FROM warning w
                        INNER JOIN [user] u ON w.user_id = u.id"
    >
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Remember, in page load this will be executed and you **don't** need to call it anywhere.

Now, on the filter button click you want to filter the records. I have the following code:

```
protected void filter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Filter();
}

protected void Filter()
{
        warningdatasource.SelectCommand= @"SELECT w.id, w.user_id, w.type, w.title, w.content, w.date, w.writer1, 
                    w.writer2, w.committeecoordinator, w.youthcoordinator, 
                    u.firstname + ' ' + u.fathername + ' ' + u.lastname AS name 
                FROM warning w
                INNER JOIN [user] u ON w.user_id = u.id
                Where u.id = @user_id
                AND w.type = @type
                AND w.title = @title
                AND w.date = @xdate";
        if (warningdatasource.SelectParameters.Count > 0)
        {
            warningdatasource.SelectParameters["user_id"].DefaultValue = userlist.SelectedValue;
            warningdatasource.SelectParameters["type"].DefaultValue = type.SelectedValue;
            warningdatasource.SelectParameters["title"].DefaultValue = title.Text;
            warningdatasource.SelectParameters["xdate"].DefaultValue = xdate.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            warningdatasource.SelectParameters.Add("user_id", TypeCode.Int32, userlist.SelectedValue);
            warningdatasource.SelectParameters.Add("type", TypeCode.Int32, type.SelectedValue);
            warningdatasource.SelectParameters.Add("title", TypeCode.String, title.Text);
            warningdatasource.SelectParameters.Add("xdate", TypeCode.DateTime, xdate.Text);
        }
}
```

Now I am getting expected result:
[image]

You can download my test project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0OVlvUE9EQVlZUU0/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Yes, I know. I cant figure out how you are populating the "type" dropdownlist. Also, you probably want to show the gridview on button click. In that case you have to write code in `filter_Click` event method.

Comment: I wrote in the method gridview1.DataBind()
but the mistake is in the query because i try it multiple time

Comment: I saw the code and try it but still there is an error in grid view on filter click it's disapeare

Comment: @Samy Sammour - You can download the test project and compare it with yours. You will find the link to download at the bottom of my answer.